# Git rebase tries to apply changes to wrong file

Tags: git, rebase

I have a problem understanding what goes wrong in the following scenario:

I have a feature branch X that is behind on `development`, so I do a rebase of this feature branch by calling `git rebase development` when the `HEAD` is on this feature branch X. Git now replays all commits of my feature branch on `development`, and it stops on a commit that has conflicts. I fixed the conflict by removing some files that shouldn't be there in the first place and added the folder to my `.gitignore` then I continue by staging the changes and `git rebase --continue`.
Now the rebase stops again on a commit that has changes to some of the files that I removed earlier. However, instead of noting that this specific file does not exist anymore, `git` tries to apply the changes to a different file in the folder!

Why is this default behavior? (I run Git 2.0)

The diff of the conflicting file is like this:

```
++<<<<<<< HEAD:<path>/XML/fileA.xslt
+ [...]  
+  
++=======
+ [....]
+       
++>>>>>>> <commit message>:<path>/XML/fileB.html
```

Comment: Did you try the command `git rebase -i development`? This will allow you to control every steps of the rebase.

Comment: I actually did an interactive rebase, but for the sake of clearity I left it out of the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is this default behavior?

Each commit stores a tree of the files, when you rebase ( as I understand ) it simply merges each commit commit in starting from the base commit.

What happens when you resolve the conflict by say removing the file `fileA.xslt` in the directory `/XML/` which is itself is stored as a tree is something like this :

```
git ls-tree HEAD XML/
... blob ... fileA.xslt
... blob ... fileB.html
```

After removal the XML directory tree looks something like this :

```
git ls-tree HEAD XML/
... blob ... fileB.html
```

Now if you try to merge it again with a tree with the removed file present ( the commit where it is modified ) :

```
git ls-tree HEAD XML/
... blob ... fileA.xslt
... blob ... fileB.html
```

So my guess is to match it will probably try to convert the `fileB.html` into `fileA.xst` as they are both the first file in the different versions of the `XML` tree or have been determined to be very similar.

---

BTW : You can do an interactive rebase and edit, skip, or reorder the commits if it is necessary.

Comment: I normally always do the rebases interactively exactly because it offers great flexibility in fixing up the commits. However the scenario depicted above kept popping up and left me scratching my head. I left the interactive part out because I thought it might be confusing and it had no actual impact on the problem at hand.
Thanks for the explanation, still think this should not be default behavior though....

Comment: Can you post `git ls-tree COMMIT_SHA XML/` output for each commit being rebased including the commit that resolved the first conflict and the conflicting commit on the second conflict? It would help try to determine where `git` may have thought there was a rename and debug the issue, because it definitely does not seem like it should be the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Because git doesn't record changes made, just snapshots, your changes were erroneously detected as renaming .xml to .html and replacing its' content with content of .html file. I think there might be some switch that provides hints for git on that matter, but I'm not sure.